# Dynamic Buttons and Text symbols with alignment "Auto" not "Fixed" in React-Sketch app

Tags: react-sketchapp

Maybe someone could help out a react-sketchapp beginner here.

Working off of the great examples Symbols and Styleguide code base, I've been able to start my own styleguide to use at work.

My question is, how do I get the text, once rendered in Sketch, to have the Alignment as Auto and not Fixed? I want it rendered out of the code that way and not have to do that in Sketch every time I drop a symbol on the artboard.

Also, is there a way to code a button that would basically perform the same as say the "Dynamic Button" plugin you can install?

Thanks in advance. You guys are brilliant for developing this app and giving it to us!!!